# knockoutjs computed not able to access observable value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I think I'm 99% there with this. I have a ko.computed that works if it references observables in the data binding. However when I attempt to get the value of the observable in the ko.computed, I get an error. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rZLjE/9/ as you can see the span bound to `plusTwo().name` updates as desired. Based on that fact I feel like having plusOne() return something like `self.selectedData().name + "other text"` should work, but that creates an error.

What am I not understanding about this code?

Thanks.

and the code for posterity

```
function Student(data) {
  this.name = ko.observable(data);
};

function ViewModel(students) {
  var self = this;
  self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedData = ko.observable();
  self.plusOne = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selectedData() + " why can't I get this to combine with selectedData!!!!";}, this);
  self.plusTwo = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.selectedData();
  }, this);
  students.forEach(function (student) {
    self.students.push(new Student(student));
  });};
var initData = ["koa", "pine", "rosewood"];
window.appViewModel = new ViewModel(initData);
ko.applyBindings(window.appViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr style="vertical-align:top">
    <td>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: {focus: $parent.selectedData}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div data-bind="if: selectedData"> 
            <span data-bind="text: selectedData().name"></span>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span data-bind="text: plusOne()"></span>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span data-bind="text: plusTwo().name"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error as the property selectedData is not initialized. Initializing with an empty student object will solve your issue.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/rZLjE/10/)

```
 self.selectedData = ko.observable(new Student(''));

 self.plusOne = ko.computed(function () {
        return  this.selectedData().name() 
                      + " I can now combine with selectedData!!!!";
}, this);
```